# Bayesian optmization when the relationship on some variables linear, and non-linear on other features

Tags: gaussian-process, bayesian-optimization

I am working on a Bayesian Optimization problem, where the approximator is GP, and the utility function is UCB1. My problem is the output of the function is linear on some features while non-linear on other features.

Meaning:

Let's say we have six features in total where the behavior of the function is non-linear on the first three features and completely linear on the remaining three features (keeping all variables the same and changing single linear feature will result in 100% correlation between changes of that variable and output of the function) as you can imagine, with 100% correlation optimum for linear features always the upper bound values provided by me.

My problem is Bayesian optimization with the setup GP (with Mattern kernel) and UCB1 fails to converge to upper bound of the linear features explained above.

Bounds for all features are between [-0.15, +0.15].

I know that:

- We can remove linear features from optimization since we know where the optimum lies
- Or we can set bounds accordingly for linear features so we restrict the space

But I am looking for a solution other than above 2, also I want to understand reasoning behind this result I am getting

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you are trying to optimize something like $y = f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6)$, and $f$ is linear on $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and non-linear on $(x_4,x_5,x_6)$. As you can imagine, it does not have anything to do with the kernel (Matern, square exponential, etc.), but rather the global mean/trend function in the underlying GP.

- For efficiency, you can improve by setting the polynomial order of the global trend to 1, so that it includes linear terms.
- Ignoring the first one is fine, GP is supposed to approximate pretty well for a 6d problem.
- If the BO does not converge, probably it has something to do with either (1) optimal criteria for convergence or (2) fitting GP.

In principle, your application should be well solved by Bayesian optimization. You can try a different implementation to see if a better result can be obtained.